# How do I resize and dispose my JFrame window?

Tags: java, swing

So I'm taking my first course Java and I'm stumped on my final project. I had to create the game Sokoban from the ground up given a levelReader from my prof. Now my entire game works correctly; tiles are painted, player and boxes move correctly, etc.

However, I have two issues that are minor. These can practically be ignored for final submission but I want to figure this out so I have a more solid understanding.

So my two issues are

a) after the last level is completed (`level == totalLevels` where level `1` is index `0`) the window is disposed and

b) I want every new level generated by initLevel to resize the window.

```
public void initLevel(int level) {
    if(level == totalLevels) { this.dispose(); } //incorrect, unsure what to use

    /* 
    .
    . BODY
    .
    */

    this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50*currentLevel.length, 50*currentLevel[0].length));
    //sets the window size initially but succeeding levels don't resize

    repaint();
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    JFrame f = new JFrame("Sokoban");
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    f.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    f.add(new Sokoban("levels.txt"));
    f.pack();
    f.setVisible(true);
}
```

Unrelated code was removed from both classes.

Comment: Use something like `SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(this)` which will return a `Window` of that the component is contained within.  You can then call `dispose` or `pack` on the `Window` as needed

Comment: I may be interpreting what you've said incorrectly but if you mean `SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(this).dispose();`, it compiles but does not dispose the window.

Comment: Works find for me.  I assume the component reference you have is actually added to your window.  Try using `System.out.println(SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(this));` to see what it returns

Comment: Then the component reference you are using doesn't exist on any window.  Find a component reference that you know does...nb- I assumed `this` as you've only provided a snipt of code

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean; my grasp on this isn't very clear at the moment. Why does `this.setPreferredSize` work correctly if `this` points to null?

Follow up edit: Why does `this.setPreferredSize` only seem to work once?

Comment: `this` isn't `null`, it's just doesn't belong to any valid `Window`...

Comment: Okay so I fixed my issue by simply placing `private static JFrame f;` within my Sokoban class. Previously I declared `JFrame f = new JFrame("Sokoban");` within my main. Now `f.dispose();` works correctly with my method `initLevel()`. Now I need to find a way to make the window size dynamic. `f.setPreferredSize` does not work and `this.setPreferredSize` only seems to size the window once.

Comment: Could my issue be in `this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50*currentLevel.length, 50*currentLevel[0].length));`? The array is `currentLevel[][]` meaning the window size is set to the size of the first row and first column of this 2D array.

Comment: You should try and avoid `setPreferredSize` and try and ensure that the components you are adding are providing appropriate size hints, then `pack` can take care of the rest